# Is everything real time or are some badges given during batch jobs?

Tags: discussion

Is everything real time or are some badges given during batch jobs? e.g. reaching a page view count.

Comment: wouldn't it be a badge job then?

Comment: @blowdart: +1.  I love a bad pun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Badges are given by background jobs running at various frequencies. You usually only have to wait a couple of minutes or so for the badge to turn up.

I would guess that the Woot/Enthusiast and Fanatic badge jobs will only run two or three times a day at most, while the Nice Answer/Question badges will run every 5-10 minutes or so.

I would also guess that these frequencies are subject to change as Jeff & co balance the load on the servers.

Comment: And the specialist badges seem to only run once or twice a day.

Comment: @mmyers: The specialist badges run everyday at 3am PST.