# The reputation process has changed, but does that affect how users earn badges?

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges, enlightened-badge, nice-answer

I have posted an answer to [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510839/force-users-to-logout-when-they-leave-my-php-website/2510853#2510853) and received 11 upvotes. If you [view my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166712/anthony-forloney) I have received the `Enlightened` badge from it, but not the `Nice Answer`.

Has the reputation change in any way affected how we earn badges?

Comment: Meta-discussion: Are we supposed to use the 'bug' tag for bug reports that we know aren't actually bugs? I put in 'discussion' instead.

Comment: Er, I had thought it was at discussion, thank you for replacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those badges use vote counts, so I doubt it.

Perhaps you have to wait a little, or perhaps it's a bug related to something else, not the reputation change.

Another thing that comes to mind (but is pure speculation), is that perhaps an old answer of you got deleted, so the process detects that you need to have (for example) 3 badges, and it's counting the one you got from the deleted answer (perhaps to a migrated question).

Comment: Your second guess is correct. He has four answers of +10 or more and four Nice Answer badges.

Comment: Ah that could be true, a recent question that was closed earned me the Nice Answer badge.

Comment: @Anthony: Was it just closed, or also deleted?  You should still get Nice Answer for closed questions, AFAIK.  (And you'd keep the badge once earned if the answer was later deleted.)

Comment: @gno, if it's closed and migrated, all answers are deleted

Comment: Yeah the badge was kept after it was closed, but then I had 4 `Nice Answer` badges with 3 10+ answers, and then when I got the `Enlightened` I was expecting another `Nice Answer` badge, but I guess SO see's 4 Badges (*remember the badge from the closed question*) and 4 10+ answers, so it thinks everything is fine.

Comment: And that's by-design btw

Answer (score 1):

See : [Is everything real time or are some badges given during batch jobs?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10441/is-everything-real-time-or-are-some-badges-given-during-batch-jobs)

Quote:

> You usually only have to wait a
>   couple of minutes or so for the badge
>   to turn up.

Comment: It was yesterday when I got the 11 upvotes, but I believe Downvoter's answer is correct.